# Does Prisma support composite keys with one of the attribute being NULL for PostgreSQL?

Tags: prisma

In PostgreSQL you can make a table with 2 columns as the composite key of that table, with one of them being NULL-able. I was just wondering how I can achieve this with Prisma.

In the current version of Prisma that I have (3.14.0), Prisma does allow composite key using `@@id([column1,column2])`, but only if those two columns are mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Prisma doesn't support composite keys with optional columns. ID Definitions are required.

Example:

This would work

```
model Post {
  title   String
  content String

  @@id([title, content])
}
```

But this wouldn't as column content is defined as optional

```
model Post {
  title   String
  content String?

  @@id([title, content])
}
```

You can create a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) here to support allowing nullable columns in composite id.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Thank you though! 